# Facing issue while submitting the form - "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var EmailContainer = $('#EmailContainer');
    var url = EmailContainer.attr('data-url');
    EmailContainer.load(url, function () {
        var Emailform = $('#EmailForm');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(Emailform);
        Emailform.submit(function () {
            debugger;
            var Emailform = $(this);
            if (Emailform.valid()) {
                var SendEmailUrl = EmailContainer.attr('Json-Url');
                var UserModel = { From: $('#From').val(), To: $('#To').val(), 
                      Subject: $('#Subject').val(), 
                      Description: $('#Description').val() }
                $.post(SendEmailUrl, UserModel, function (data) {
                    Emailform.html(data);
                    Emailform.removeData('validator');
                    Emailform.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(Emailform);
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

**Admin Controller Partial View**

```
@model _1.Areas.Email.Models.User
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EmailForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.From);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.From);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.From);
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.To);                           
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.To); 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.To);
    <br />     
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Subject);                           
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Subject);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Subject);
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Description);                           
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Description);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Description);
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email" id="SendMail" />
}
```

**Issue - When submitting the partial view of admin controller. it is giving "500 Internal Server Error"**

[image]

**Update - 1**

As you can see in the Partial View - I am mentioning the action in HTML.BeginForm and also I have submit form. I think request is being submitted more then once?

Comment: You'll need to specify what the error is. The response tab in your dev tools should display it.

Comment: Updated my query. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states you the application is trying to find a View called "SendMail" this is because of your line below requesting one.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendMail(User Model)
{
    new MailController().SendMail(Model).DeliverAsync();
    return View(); // this is causing a redirect to a get version of this call
                   // asking for a view.
}
```

Do you intend on returning HTML or a JSON response? If HTML then add a view; if not return a `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery and AJAX, the MVC will send any error pages back to the client, but since the status code is not "200 OK" but "500 internal server error", jQuery won't run the callback function you gave it with the AJAX call.

Your problem is, that the mail template(view, .vbhtml) cannot be found.

```
return Email("SendMail", model);
```

The above Code tells the Controller to find a view called "SendMail.vbhtml".
In your last picture you can see, where MVC looked for the "SendMail.vbhtml":
`~/Areas/Email/Views/Admin`   and
`~/Views/Shared`

Putting your view in one of those folders should fix the problem